# How do I fix my wiper?

Tags: windshield-wipers

My passenger side wiper arm came completely off of the car. the nodule it was attached to still moves when the wipers are turned on but the entire arm, blade etc will not stay attached to the car..is there a way this can be fixed without having to replace the whole wiper transmission? if so what is the piece called...it appears to just be a small piece that fits down in the hole on the wiper arm to hold it in place...i have thought about just tack welding it but fear that would only temporarily solve the issue. thanks for the help.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! We need to know what kind of car you have (year/make/model) in order to help. A picture of what you're talking about would also be of great assistance, so we can see what's going on.

Comment: Please post make, model, and year of your vehicle and a photo.

Comment: And please put all that requested info into the original post by editing it.  Then we'd be better equipped to help.